# Forcing the less inline-elements to the first line

Tags: html, css, positioning

Random number of divs are placed via javascript in my container div.

```
<div id="container"></div>
#container { text-align: center; width: 480px; }
#container div { display: inline-block; width: 100px; }
```

With these styles I managed to position the small divs to the center of the container.
4 of them can fit a line, if there are more the rest are placed in the next line.
When there are less than 4 divs in the last line, space at left and right sides of them appearing.

Is it possible to force these empty spaces (always) into the first line? (Keeping the smallest number of elements in the 1st line instead of last.)

Would love a pure CSS solution (but if that doesn't exist, anything else will be OK of course). Thanks!

```
What I have:
|    _____   _____   _____   _____    |
|   |     | |     | |     | |     |   |
|   |  1  | |  2  | |  3  | |  4  |   |
|   |_____| |_____| |_____| |_____|   |
|            _____   _____            |
|           |     | |     |           |
|           |  5  | |  6  |           |
|           |_____| |_____|           |

What I want:
|            _____   _____            |
|           |     | |     |           |
|           |  1  | |  2  |           |
|           |_____| |_____|           |
|    _____   _____   _____   _____    |
|   |     | |     | |     | |     |   |
|   |  3  | |  4  | |  5  | |  6  |   |
|   |_____| |_____| |_____| |_____|   |
```

Comment: Some more info: The solution doesn't need to keep the small divs' original order, it doesn't matter in my project (reverse order is OK too, can be any). Just wanna have the shortest (if there is) at top. In case there are let's say 12 divs, there should be no empty spacing, just 3 full lines. Maybe it could be done with javascript too, might also be interesting. What I think: it could check the number of total divs and adding margins accordingly while putting the divs into my container. I need the solution to work with 6 divs per line too (instead of 4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think at best you can do some hacks:

**Option 1:**

Use a `flexbox` and `wrap-reverse` it:

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 480px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap-reverse;
  justify-content:center;
}
#container div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</div>
```

**Option 2:**

Another thing you can do is using `transform` scaling:

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 480px;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
#container div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:5px;
  display:inline-block;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</div>
```

Let me know your feedback on this, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! The 2nd one seems nice. I wonder if there will be other type of solutions though (simpler / less hacky).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**. You can smartly use `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;`, and it will do the job.

Have a look at the code below:

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.box-holder {
  width: 280px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="box-holder">
    <div class="box one">1</div>
    <div class="box two">2</div>
    <div class="box three">3</div>
    <div class="box four">4</div>
    <div class="box five">5</div>
    <div class="box six">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, but sadly: "Internet Explorer 10 and earlier versions do not support the flex-wrap property." I think I might lose more than what I'd win. :(

Comment: @JaSon IE10 is now an obsolete, unsupported browser. There's no more reason to support it than there is to support IE6.

Comment: @JaSon Yes! these browsers are too obsolete. Because Flexbox is changing the way we all use CSS and these guys isn't implemented it yet...

Answer (score 0):

i fixed your issued see my below solution that support IE9 also. i fixed using child element.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{text-align:center;width:400px}
.container div{width:100px;height:100px;background:red;display:inline-block;margin-left: -4px;}
.container div:first-child{margin-left:100px;}
.container div:nth-child(2){margin-right:100px;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hardyrajput/Ly8667n3/2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though your solution is only good for fixed number (6) divs. I doubled the divs and got a red cross (2 in first and 2 in 4th line). (In that case there should be no empty space at all.)